# Is there a way to get the audio playing from the speakers of a device

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

So I've been battling with an issue for a while now, I've been trying to get the audio playing through the speakers of a device using the MediaDevices singleton object in javascript.
I'm trying to achieve something similar to Shazam or snapchat where they can both get the audio playing from the speakers of a device and also from a microphone so that I can for instance be taking a video using my microphone and video cam and also streaming the sound playing from the background.

I'll like to know if this is possible because I tried using devices with kind of "**audiooutput**" and deviceId of "**default**" accessible through the enumerateDevices method assuming that's the device's output speaker but I still get the audio from the microphone even when using the device kind of "**audiooutput**".

Note: I'm able to combine multiple audio nodes successfully.

I'm not asking for a do it for me answer, just a theory of how to go about implementing it if it's possible in javascript.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible via the Web Audio API.  Not all platforms even support this capability.

On some platforms, you can use [`getDisplayMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia) and get audio with it, but compatibility isn't great right now.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, been battling with this for days, thought there was something missing

Comment: Well there goes my dream of doing something like that :)

Comment: @PrinceSule Depending on your budget and target platforms, you can always bolt-on a native solution and pipe the data in via browser plugin or similar.  There are also loopback audio drivers available.